# Adding width and height to local image in new mail in outlook with win32com(Python)

Tags: python, windows, outlook, win32com

Why I cant pass width and height to local images in img tag. Code below is working(image is displaying) but when I add `width="100" height="200"` to img tag image is not displayed. When I change `src` to image on the web `src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GafDJ.jpg?s=256&g=1"` and add width="100" height="200" image is displayed with added dimensions.

```
import os
import win32com.client as client
outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
icon = os.getcwd() + '\\test.jpg'

html_body = f'''
<img src="{icon}">
<!-- <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GafDJ.jpg?s=256&g=1" width="100" height="200"> -->

'''

mail.To = ''
mail.CC = ''
mail.Subject = ''
mail.HTMLBody = html_body
mail.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Local images need to be added as attachments, otherwise the actual image doesn't get sent with the email. The process that has worked for me in the past is to add the image file as an attachment then reference it as a property from the html in the mail.

For example:

```
import os
import win32com.client as client

outlook = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(client.constants.olMailItem)
icon = os.getcwd() + '\\Test.jpg'

#Add a new attachment, putting 0 as third argument means the file is hidden
att = mail.Attachments.Add(icon,client.constants.olByValue,0)

#Create a Content Id (cid) for this image. Can be whatever you want: I'm using short filename
cidName = icon.split('\\')[-1]
att.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty('http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F', cidName);
    
imgTag = '<img src="cid:{0:}" width="100" height="200">'.format(cidName)

mail.To = ''
mail.CC = ''
mail.Subject = ''
mail.HTMLBody = imgTag
mail.Save()
```

I am not an expert on how the whole 'schema' thing works, but it seems to do the job. NB. I've used `gencache.EnsureDispatch()` rather than just `Dispatch()`. I've found this ensures that the Outlook constants are available (eg `olByValue`) rather than just using hard-coded numbers.

Comment: I can send the mail with image when I don't specify the width and height.

Comment: @IGRACH I see what you mean! I now recall having to go the attachment route because my images weren't turning up correctly. There are quite a few links about Outlook not rendered HTML 'correctly', eg: https://blog.jmwhite.co.uk/2014/03/28/solving-dpi-scaling-issues-with-html-email-in-outlook/